# Vanilla Javascript & Dom Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, events, dom

I've been learning Javascript online and have recently started to put it to use on a website. I'm still a little confused about what might be the most efficient/performant ways to do things, though. A few questions with that in mind...

1. If a webpage has multiple click events in different sections, each doing something different, one event listener in the body tag — with multiple if/else statements — would be the most efficient way to handle them all. Is that correct?
2. Is the search method a good way to handle if/else statements in this case? For example:

   ```
   if (event.target.className.search("js-tab") !== -1) {
   // do something
   } else if (event.target.className.search("js-dropdown") !== -1) {
   // do something else
   }
   ```
3. The ID performance only applies to actually finding an element, right? There wouldn't be a difference between event.target.className.search and event.target.id.search, would there? (assuming there aren't an insane amount of class names to search through on that element). I'm currently using className for sections that have the same functionality (multiple tabbed sections on the same page, for example). I suppose I could just as easily use the or operator if it made a difference, like so:

   ```
   if ((event.target.id.search("js-tab-one") !== -1) || (event.target.id.search("js-tab-two") !== -1))
   ```
4. When there are multiple elements that a click event could potentially be on (an icon inside of an anchor link, for example), how much of a performance hit is it to add additional if/else statements (i.e. check the tag type, and if it's not the a tag, move up)? I recently refactored my css so that my icons were set to width: 100% and height: 100% (ensuring that the click was always happening on the same element every time), but I wonder how much of a performance boost (if any at all) I actually got by doing this?

Comment: That is a very heavy set of questions you've got there.

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure if I should split them up into multiple posts/questions?

Comment: i'd probably split this up for future reference and go to code review actually instead of SO (as I know it SO deals with problems usually though you can find performance optimizations) code review is for performance, but i'm trying to type an answer right now, so don't feel the need to delete this one

Comment: also i heard if you delete too many questions then you get penalized, so don't delete questions if possible

Comment: I think a lot of your questions could be answered with "Do not prematurely optimize". Lots and lots of "neat inventive systems" that intelligent new developers come up with actually end up hurting their performance. If you write JavaScript like a C programmer, trying to cheat out performance, chances are it'll perform worse than the guy following random JQuery tutorials next to you. For the most part, base your work off what you can write and modify the fastest, and what's the most common / standard practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a webpage has multiple click events in different sections, each
>   doing something different, one event listener in the body tag — with
>   multiple if/else statements — would be the most efficient way to
>   handle them all. Is that correct?

No. It's useful for handling events on elements that you add dynamically, but not so much for regular events.

Handling all the events in the body means that you will handle *all* the events. Every click that happens goes through your code to see if it comes from one of the elements that you are interested in.

> Is the search method a good way to handle if/else statements in this
>   case?

No. The `search` method uses a regular expression, not a string, so the string will be parsed to create a RegExp object. Then a search is done using the regular expression, which is slower than a normal string search, and can give unexpected results.

To look for a string in another string you should use the `indexOf` method instead. You should however be aware that it will look for a match anywhere in the string, not matching whole class names. It will for example find `"all-head"` when the element has the class `"small-header"`.

> The ID performance only applies to actually finding an element, right?

Yes.

> When there are multiple elements that a click event could potentially
>   be on (an icon inside of an anchor link, for example), how much of a
>   performance hit is it to add additional if/else statements (i.e. check
>   the tag type, and if it's not the a tag, move up)?

That means that every click event will have to go through the extra `if` statements.

If you bind the event to the element instead, you know that the event happened inside that element and you don't have to know which element did actually catch it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of what you're asking is subjective though and it fits in the context that is trying to happen. So there might be a reason why the below might be not good (as another commenter said, don't prematurely optimize). But there are some programming techniques that can be said about what you have done, namely modularity. There's a few performance considerations but they mostly revolve around writing good code:

1) it really depends on your handler, if you intend to delete and add DOM elements, this can be better because you watch the document instead of tying in a new click handler to each element. but this can be bad because its not modular if you have it do too much stuff. But if its just looking at the state, then this is not really good performance wise....

2) i wouldn't say that the search has any impact on the if else's, but in considering optimization of this particular situation you describe later on, I wouldn't do that. As each time you go through each if-else you end up doing another search and it can add up in the long run if you have a lot of if-elses in the way.

3) there shouldn't be a difference but why search in an id string? unless your id string is part of some unholy long part like musical-js-tab-one-musical-tab which I wouldn't suggest to use as an id like this anyway, you should split it up, you shouldn't tie functionality like that, use classes instead like class='musical' id='js-tab-one' since id's should describe a singular object on the page.

4) everytime you add an if-else, no matter how small it is, is another computer cycle and a little bit more memory. and it can add up, just attach your click handler by tag and by class at this point and let the browser decide to optimize it.